# how to add string array elements to arraylist in java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

How do I add string array elements to an arraylist?

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    List<BudgetEntity> budgetEntityList = new ArrayList<>(20); 
    BudgetEntity budgetEntity = new BudgetEntity();

    String budgetID[] = request.getParameterValues("budgetID");

for(int i=0;   i < budgetID.length ;   i++) {

      for(int k=0;   k < budgetEntityList.size() ;   k++) {

          budgetEntity=  budgetEntityList.get(k);
      }

            budgetEntity.setTotal(Integer.valueOf(budgetID[i]));
        }
```

Comment: I get this Exception ....java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at com.watanialivestock.contoller.BudgetSaveServlet.doPost(BudgetSaveServlet.java:75)

Comment: Please, edit you question with this exception, also, see [ask] to write a correct question.

Comment: Also the stacktrace (however hard to read in the comment) refers to line 75 of Budg‌​etSaveServlet.java. Which line is that?

Comment: Like already said, improve your question by editing it. If you ask for the reason of an exception, what is the relation to adding string array elements to an arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `budgetEntityList` is empty when you do `budgetEntity=  budgetEntityList.get(k);`

Doing a `new ArrayList<>(capacity)` does not fill your ArrayList with BudgetList objects, it only sets the initial capacity of your ArrayList.

So, what you need to do is:

```
 for(int k=0;   k < budgetEntityList.size() ;   k++) {
      budgetEntity = new BudgetEntity();
      budgetEntityList.add(budgetEntity);
  }
```

And then, set the total of your BudgetEntity